# How to download a PDF file from the Chrome PDF print view

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I am trying to create a puppeteer script to download a PDF file. I feel like I'm totally over complicating this! Here's an example of what I want to automate:

1. Go to https://www.espn.com/sports-betting/story/_/id/35852378/2023-ncaa-men-tournament-march-madness-printable-brackets-college-basketball
2. Click on the text/link "NCAA Tournament Printable Bracket". The document loads in the Chrome PDF window.
3. Save the PDF file.

**EDIT:** I should have mentioned that the file is generated after clicking a button so I cannot use a specific link and download that file.

I have tried the following:

- Using the .pdf function. This prints a PDF of the print view.
- Pressing Cmd + A. This isn't supported by Chrome with Mac it looks like because it's a native function.
- Tabbing to the save button and pressing the enter button. This doesn't work because the Mac save modal isn't visible to puppeteer.

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function run() {
  // const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto('https://www.espn.com/sports-betting/story/_/id/35852378/2023-ncaa-men-tournament-march-madness-printable-brackets-college-basketball');

  const html = await page.content();

  await page.waitForSelector('#article-feed > article:nth-child(1) > div > div.article-body > ul > li:nth-child(1) > p > a > em > strong');

  // Print and save test 1
  await page.pdf({
    path: 'bracket.pdf',
    format: 'A4'
  });

  // Print and save test 2
  await page.keyboard.press('Tab');
  await page.keyboard.press('Tab');
  await page.keyboard.press('Tab');
  await page.keyboard.press('Tab');
  await page.keyboard.press('Tab');
  await page.keyboard.press('Tab');
  await page.keyboard.press('Tab');
  await page.keyboard.press('Tab');
  await page.keyboard.press('Enter');
  await page.keyboard.press('Enter');

  // Print and save test 3
  await page.evaluate(() => {
    window.print = function() {};
  });

  // Print and save test 4
  await page.keyboard.down('Cmd');
  await page.keyboard.down('S');
  await page.keyboard.up('S');
  await page.keyboard.up('Cmd');
  await page.waitForTimeout(5000);
  await page.keyboard.up('Enter');

  await browser.close();
}

run();
```

Comment: Let me know if I’m missing something obvious, but why not just skip the entire Puppeteer thing and download [the bracket straight from the CDN](https://a.espncdn.com/i/ncaa/basketball/ncaatourney23/ncaam_bracket_filled.pdf) using `fetch` and write the response to your filesystem?

Comment: @esqew the bracket was just an example. I'm actually downloading a different file from another page (not on espn.com), but the workflow is longer so I just shared this example.

Comment: Hmm. That sort of kills the [mcve] here then. Automating a totally different workflow than you're actually using won't do you much good. Downloads can be pretty fussy and involve highly page-specific behavior, and as esqew pointed out, this is a trivial example that doesn't necessitate Puppeteer at all. Please share an accurate example of whatever you're actually using, or something that's 1:1 representative of it (careful with this! it's easy to introduce a difference) so we can automate the right thing. Thanks.

Comment: I understand. The reason I used this very simple example is because I am specifically having an issue with the printing part. Nonetheless, I understand the ask.